# NgRx reach action's payload inside flatMap's function

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I'm relatively new to NgRx, I've been using it for only a few months, and there's this issue I've been struggling with for days, and never found anything useful in the documentation about this.

I'm using Angular 8 with NgRx 8 as well. This is my pretty simple, dummy code.

**getItems action**

```
export interface GetItems {
  param: number;
}

export const getItems = createAction("[App] Get items", props<GetItems>());
```

**getItems effect:**

```
getItems$ = createEffect(
() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AppActions.getItems),
    tap((action) => console.log(action.param),
    exhaustMap(action => this.appService.getItems()),
    map((response: Item[]) => {
      console.log(action.param);

      return this.store.dispatch(
        AppActions.getItemsComplete({ items: response })
      );
    })
  ),
  { dispatch: false }
);
```

**Dispatching getItems action:**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  const param: number = 99;

  this.store.dispatch(getItems({ param }));
}
```

Is there a way to reach the action's *param* payload *inside* the exhaustMap operator? As you can see here, the second *console.log* will push an error about the missin action object. My goal is: send a request to the *appService* first (without the *getItems* action parameter though), then dispatch the *getItemsComplete* action WITH the *getItems* action parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be this:

```js
getItems$ = createEffect(
() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(AppActions.getItems),
    tap((action) => console.log(action.param),
    exhaustMap(action => forkJoin(of(action), this.appService.getItems())),
    map(([action, response]) => {
      console.log(action.param);

      return this.store.dispatch(
        AppActions.getItemsComplete({ items: response })
      );
    })
  ),
  { dispatch: false }
);
```

[forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) will make sure that both observables complete, then it will delegate the response array further down the pipe. You can have `N` observables passed to `forkJoin`, but you'll get the array response once **all complete**.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, sadly I didn't know forkJoin will do the trick! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad it helped! [Here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom) is a great article explaining `forkJoin` and the similar operators. It provides very accurate analogies for each of them.